# Change the order of columns in bootstrap 3 grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have html like below, [This is a jsbin post](http://jsbin.com/yaqobafi/1/edit).

I want the blue and red div swap their location in `xs` size.

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">
           red
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;">
           blue
       </div>
   </div>
```

Is it possible in bootstrap 3.0 to change the order of columns in mobile size.

Comment: I recommend to use a jQuery or Javascript technique,to swap their positions.

Comment: If using css is not posible i will use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here change the order of divs and float them right with pull-right class from bootstrap http://jsbin.com/fowohuro/1/edit

Comment: But this does not work when using col-sm-12. It is possible with a col-sm-12?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is easily done with push and pull classes.

First, change the source order so that it is in the order you want it to be at the smallest size.  So, I swapped the red and blue divs to be blue first and red second.  Then, you need to add the push and pull classes.  You'll be pushing the blue column and pulling the red column...et voilà

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6" style="background-color:blue;">
           blue
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6" style="background-color:red;">
           red
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the many useful things in Bootstrap that is just brushed over in the doc... cheers!

Comment: This does not work when using col-sm-12. Note that the order in sm is different.

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish then.  Your question asked how to change the element order at xs size.  If you want the elements to be full width at sm size then you'll need to use the col-sm-12 classes and push/pull with the col-md-push-x / col-md-pull-x classes.  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  Check the section under Column Ordering.